# Ways to trigger Synapse Pipeline when Sharepoint files are modified

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-synapse

I'm looking for a way to trigger a Synapse pipeline (runs a Databricks notebook and web activities to refresh PowerBI) whenever a file is modified.

Let's say I got a data.xlsx on my Sharepoint site folder and I add a new row to it, is there a way to automatically trigger a pipeline when such event happens by only using Azure Synapse or do I need to make use of Power Apps or Logic Apps to then trigger Synapse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no trigger type in Synapse pipeline that can be activated by a change in a Sharepoint file.

Here is a list of available trigger types - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers .

You will have to trigger the pipeline from an external tool, like Power Apps or Logic Apps, as you said.